# PHP Sort associative multidimensional array by another array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have an array of order `$order`. I want to sort an associative array by this array by the `article` field. The point is to sort also other elements in this array such as `title` by that order. If there are more elements in the array than in sorting array, then leave them in their place as shown in the example below:

**Input data:**

```
$data = array(
    "title" => array("title 1", "title 2", "title 3", "title 4", "title 5", "title 6"),
    "article" => array("01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06")
);

$order = ["03", "01", "04", "02"];
```

**Expected result:**

```
$data = array(
    "title" => array("title 3", "title 1", "title 4", "title 2", "title 5", "title 6"),
    "article" => array("03", "01", "04", "02", "05", "06")
);
```

Comment: Hi Andrew, what is your question exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a solution, but it is as ugly as the quality of the initial data you have:

```
<?php
$input = [
    "title" => ["title 1", "title 2", "title 3", "title 4", "title 5", "title 6"],
    "article" => ["01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06"]
];
$order = ["03", "01", "04", "02"];
$output = [];

// pick ordered items
foreach($order as $article) {
    $position = array_search($article, $input['article']);
    foreach (array_keys($input) as $key) {
        $output[$key][] = $input[$key][$position];
    }
}

// fill in the rest
foreach ($input['article'] as $position => $article) {
    foreach (array_keys($input) as $key) {
        if (!in_array($article, $order)) {
            $output[$key][] = $input[$key][$position];
        }
    }
}

var_dump($output);
```

The output obviously is:

```
array(2) {
  ["title"]=>
  array(6) {
    [0]=>
    string(7) "title 3"
    [1]=>
    string(7) "title 1"
    [2]=>
    string(7) "title 4"
    [3]=>
    string(7) "title 2"
    [4]=>
    string(7) "title 5"
    [5]=>
    string(7) "title 6"
  }
  ["article"]=>
  array(6) {
    [0]=>
    string(2) "03"
    [1]=>
    string(2) "01"
    [2]=>
    string(2) "04"
    [3]=>
    string(2) "02"
    [4]=>
    string(2) "05"
    [5]=>
    string(2) "06"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Provided you have the same number of items in each, we can build a map of old positional keys to new positionals keys, and then use array_multisort to sort these into place, and sort the corresponding arrays in the same order.

```
<?php
$data = array(
    "title" => array("title 1", "title 2", "title 3", "title 4", "title 5", "title 6"),
    "article" => array("01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06")
);

$new_order = ["03", "01", "04", "02"];
$old_order = $data['article'];

// Build a map of before and after key positions.
foreach($old_order as $k => $value) {
    $key = array_search($value, $new_order);
    if($key === false) // No positional change.
        $key = $k;
    $map[$k] = $key; // old position -> new position
}

array_multisort($map, $data['title'], $data['article']);
var_export($data);
```

Output:

```
array (
  'title' => 
  array (
    0 => 'title 3',
    1 => 'title 1',
    2 => 'title 4',
    3 => 'title 2',
    4 => 'title 5',
    5 => 'title 6',
  ),
  'article' => 
  array (
    0 => '03',
    1 => '01',
    2 => '04',
    3 => '02',
    4 => '05',
    5 => '06',
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want some shorter code and less loops:

```
$properOrderedArray = array_replace(array_flip($data["article"]),array_flip($order));
array_map(function($title,$article,$properOrderedArray) use (&$newOrder){
    $newOrder['title'][$properOrderedArray]=$title;
    $newOrder['article'][$properOrderedArray]=$article;
},$data['title'],$data['article'],$properOrderedArray);
ksort($newOrder['title']);
ksort($newOrder['article']);
print_r($newOrder);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [title] => Array
        (
            [0] => title 3
            [1] => title 1
            [2] => title 4
            [3] => title 2
            [4] => title 5
            [5] => title 6
        )

    [article] => Array
        (
            [0] => 03
            [1] => 01
            [2] => 04
            [3] => 02
            [4] => 05
            [5] => 06
        )

)
```